# How to use the target command with IBM Cloud CLI

Tags: command-line-interface, ibm-cloud

After the login to IBM Cloud using the CLI command `ibmcloud login` I got the following message:

> Use 'ibmcloud target --cf' to target Cloud Foundry org/space
>   interactively, or use 'ibmcloud target --cf-api ENDPOINT -o ORG -s
>   SPACE' to target the org/space.

So I searched and find the format:

```
ibmcloud target [-r REGION_NAME] [-c ACCOUNT_ID] [-g RESOURCE_GROUP]
 [--cf] [-o ORG] [-s SPACE]
```

So I enter `ibmcloud target - Dallas-c 1770253-g Default--cf-o lior2-s lior2`.
Is there somthing wrong with my format?

Comment: In the command as you posted it, almost everything is wrong. There is a single `-` before "Dallas", and no whitespace before `-g`, `--cf`, `-o`, and `-s`. I cannot tell if those problems were introduced when you wrote the question, or if that is actually the command you tried to execute.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the interactive format `ibmcloud target --cf`. Then you are prompted to select from valid values. Remember them and the next time use them as parameters. An example could be:

```
ibmcloud target -r us-south -g default -s lior2
```

[The IBM Cloud docs for the CLI has examples for the target command](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/cli/reference/ibmcloud/bx_cli.html#ibmcloud_target).

Comment: HI #data_henrik it is possible for hire you for private lesson?